# Can I improve branch prediction with my code?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, branch-prediction, likely-unlikely

This is a naive general question open to any platform, language, or compiler.  Though I am most curious about Aarch64, C++, GCC.

When coding an unavoidable branch in program flow dependent on I/O state (compiler cannot predict), and I know that one state is much more likely than another, how do I indicate that to the compiler?

Is this better

```
if(true == get(gpioVal))
    unlikelyFunction();
else
    likelyFunction();
```

than this?

```
if(true == get(gpioVal))
    likelyFunction(); // performance critical, fill prefetch caches from this branch
else
    unlikelyFunction(); // missed prediction not consequential on this branch
```

Does it help if the communication protocol makes the more likely or critical value true(high), or false(low)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL:DR: Yes, in C or C++ use a `likely()` macro, or C++20 `[[likely]]`, to help the compiler make better asm.  That's separate from influencing actual CPU branch-prediction, though.  If writing in asm, lay out your code to minimize taken branches.

---

For most ISAs, there's no way in asm to hint the CPU whether a branch is likely to be taken or not.  (Some exceptions include Pentium 4 (but not earlier or later x86), PowerPC, and some MIPS, which allow branch hints as part of conditional-branch asm instructions.)

- [Is it possible to tell the branch predictor how likely it is to follow the branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851299/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-branch-predictor-how-likely-it-is-to-follow-the-branc)

But not-taken straight-line code is cheaper than taken, so **hinting high-level language to lay out code with the fast-path contiguous doesn't help branch prediction accuracy, but can help (or hurt) performance**.  (I-cache locality, front-end bandwidth: remember code-fetch happens in contiguous 16 or 32-byte blocks, so a taken branch means a later part of that fetch block isn't useful. Also, branch prediction *throughput*; some CPUs like Intel Skylake for example can't handle a predicted-taken branch at more than 1 per 2 clocks, other than loop branches.  That include unconditional branches like jmp or ret.)

Taken branches are hard; not-taken branches keep the CPU on its toes, but if the prediction is accurate it's just a normal instruction for an execution unit (verifying the prediction), with nothing special for the front-end.  See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) which has a section on branch prediction.  (And is overall *excellent*.)

- [What exactly happens when a skylake CPU mispredicts a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984007/what-exactly-happens-when-a-skylake-cpu-mispredicts-a-branch)
- [Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932119/avoid-stalling-pipeline-by-calculating-conditional-early)
- [How does the branch predictor know if it is not correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852649/how-does-the-branch-predictor-know-if-it-is-not-correct)

---

Many people misunderstand source-level branch hints as branch *prediction* hints.  That could be one effect if compiling for a CPU that supports branch hints in asm, but for most the significant effect is in layout, and deciding whether to use branchless (`cmov`) or not; a `[[likely]]` condition also means it should predict well.

**With some CPUs, especially older, layout of a branch did sometimes influence runtime prediction**: if the CPU didn't remember anything about the branch in its dynamic predictors, the standard static prediction heuristic is that forward conditional branches are not-taken, backward conditional are assumed taken (because that's [normally the bottom of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump).  See the BTFNT section in https://danluu.com/branch-prediction/.

A compiler can lay out an `if(c) x else y;` either way, either matching the source with `jump over x if !c` as the opening thing, or swap the if and else blocks and use the opposite branch condition. Or it can put one block out-of-line (e.g. after the `ret` at the end of the function) so the fast path has no taken branches conditional or otherwise, while the less likely path has to jump there and then jump back.

---

It's easy to do more harm than good with branch hints in high-level source, especially if surrounding code changes without paying attention to them, so profile-guided optimization is the best way for compilers to learn about branch predictability and likelihood.  (e.g. `gcc -O3 -fprofile-generate` / run with some representative inputs that exercise code-paths in relevant ways / `gcc -O3 -fprofile-use`)

But there are ways to hint in some languages, like C++20 `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]`, which are the portable version of GNU C `likely()` / `unlikely()` macros around `__builtin_expect`.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely  C++20 `[[likely]]`
- [How to use C++20's likely/unlikely attribute in if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797959/how-to-use-c20s-likely-unlikely-attribute-in-if-else-statement) syntax help
- [Is there a compiler hint for GCC to force branch prediction to always go a certain way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130930/is-there-a-compiler-hint-for-gcc-to-force-branch-prediction-to-always-go-a-certa)  (to the literal question, no.  To what's actually wanted, branch hints to the compiler, yes.)
- [How do the likely/unlikely macros in the Linux kernel work and what is their benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben/31133787#31133787)  The GNU C macros using `__builtin_expect`, same effect but different syntax than C++20 `[[likely]]`
- [What is the advantage of GCC's __builtin_expect in if else statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/what-is-the-advantage-of-gccs-builtin-expect-in-if-else-statements)  example asm output. (Also see CiroSantilli's answers to some of the other questions where he made examples.)
- [Simple example where [[likely]] and [[unlikely]] affect program assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222212/simple-example-where-likely-and-unlikely-affect-program-assembly)

I don't know of ways to annotate branches for languages other than GNU C / C++, and ISO C++20.

---

#### Absent any hints or profile data

Without that, optimizing compilers have to use heuristics to guess which side of a branch is more likely.  If it's a loop branch, they normally assume that the loop will run multiple times.  On an `if`, they have some heuristics based on the actual condition and maybe what's in the blocks being controlled; IDK I haven't looked into what gcc or clang do.

I have noticed that GCC does care about the condition, though.  It's not as naive as assuming that `int` values are uniformly randomly distributed, although I think it normally assumes that `if (x == 10) foo();` is somewhat unlikely.

JIT compilers like in a JVM have an advantage here: they can potentially instrument branches in the early stages of running, to collect branch-direction information before making final optimized asm.  OTOH they need to compile *fast* because compile time is part of total run time, so they don't try as hard to make good asm, which is a major disadvantage in terms of code quality.