# Branch prediction and UB (undefined behavior)

Tags: c++, c, cpu-architecture, undefined-behavior, branch-prediction

I know a little something about branch prediction. This happens at the CPU and has nothing to do with compilation. Although you might be able to tell the compiler if one branch is more likely than the other e.g. in C++20 via `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely)) this is seperate to the branch prediction the CPU performs (see [Can I improve branch prediction with my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600597/can-i-improve-branch-prediction-with-my-code)).

As far as I know when I have e.g. a loop (with an exit condition) the CPU will predict that the exit condition will not be met and try to perform some operations inside the loop even if the condition has not been checked yet. If the CPU predicts correct it saves some time and everything is fine. However what happens if it is not able to predict it correct? I know that this will be a performance hit but I don't know if some already done operations are discareded or reversed or just how it handles it.

Now I have come up with two simple examples. The first one (if we ignore that the compiler might just calculate the sum at compile time and I asume that no optimisations occure) should be very easy to predict for the CPU. The loop condition will be the same for the whole time and the condition in the loop only switches once. This means that the prediction will get us a nice performance boost and even if it fails a few times, adding a number can easily be reversed.

In the second example the exit condition is again easy to predict. In the loops body I allocate a new `int` array via [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Note that I don't free it on purpose since I want the allocation to succeed for a long time so the CPU predicts this success. At some time the allocation will fail when I run out of memory (I didn't calculate the total memory consumption and suppose that memory will not be moved to disk) or some other error occurs. This means that `ptr` will be `NULL` and dereferencing it is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Null_pointer_dereference). It is not defined what happens, it could just be a no-op, crash my program or cause my PC to fly away. Therefore I conclude that the CPU can not just undo that and I am wondering what happens.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VERSION 1

#if VERSION == 1
int main() {
    size_t sum = 0ull;

    for (size_t i = 0ull, max = 1'000ull; i < max;  ++i) {
        if (i < (max / 2)) {
            sum += 2 * i;
        }
        else {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

#else
int main() {
    int* ptr = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0ull, max = 1'000'000ull; i < max; ++i) {
        ptr = (int*)malloc((sizeof * ptr) * 1'000ull);

        if (ptr) {
            *ptr = 1234;
        }

        // free(ptr)
    }

    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Branch prediction is the CPUs task and UB obviously exists in C as well as in C++ so I think an answer to this doesn't require one specific language and my  code should work in both languages. If the chosen language however makes a difference I am more interested in C++ than in C but would be happy for any answers.

Comment: the CPU doesn't emit any errors until it determines that the branch is taken, ie: no writes to memory will happen until the branch is resolved, so anything that happens while the branch is not taken yet has no side-effects, except in the cpu registers, which is the root of many security vulnerabilities.

Comment: *"adding a number can easily be reversed."* That's not really how it works - a mispredicted add is not "fixed" with a subtract,  but rather by not saving the result. On *some* hardware both paths of the if-else might be speculatively executed in parallel, and then only one of them is used when the condition has been determined.

Comment: You're mixing levels of abstraction here. UB is concept of the C++ language. UB means "Standard does not put any obligation on compiler regarding such code". Your code has no UB, compiler is required to produce valid executable out of it that behaves strictly as C++ standard defined it. All that remains is a possibility of (very rare) bug in compiler or (very very rare) bug in CPU.

Comment: This isn't really related to the language at all, but to the underlying ISA. Instruction caching, pipelining, cache misses etc are handled exclusively by the CPU and not by software. Undefined behavior does not apply - a CPU is not a programming language.

Comment: @AhmedAEK The (user-accessible) CPU registers must not be affected either. Changes are actually done in internal registers. Vulnerabilities are generally due to speculative read (of data that should normally not have been accessed) + code yielding different timings depending on the value, not what happens in registers.

Comment: @vinc17 CPU registers can and will be affected - the only thing the CPU tries is to undo those changes. This can mean that it stores the state of registers when speculating and restoring it afterwards, or just having them flagged as dirty and cleaned afterwards. This is also the source of many security-bugs as the registers are changed and can have an observable impact even on other programs running.

Comment: In your second example, you've guarded the pointer dereference, so why do you think there's UB involved in that?  Once memory is exhausted, `malloc` will return null, repeatedly, but your loop body guards against using the null pointer.

Comment: @ErikEidt My thought was that the CPU might perform the derefernce before checking the condition `if (ptr)` because of branch predictions. When `ptr` was never `NULL` before it would predict that it is not gonna be `NULL`. I know that this is a silly idea because someone will definetly have had the same thought when coming up with branch predictions but I just wanted to know a bit more about it.

Comment: @Joel The CPU might very well try to access memory that the program never requests, it might even try to read or write to protected memory, but it is part of the CPUs instructions and its specification that tells you how it will behave and most of them are sane - so while they might try to do something illegal that execution is internally marked as being speculative and any actions taken by wrong predictions will be discarded. The programming language used has NO influence as the Cpu NEVER SEES THAT. Your compiler is converting your code into something the hardware can use - and thats not c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However what happens if it is not able to predict it correct?

It wastes time & energy doing work that has to be thrown away.

> This means that ptr will be NULL and dereferencing it is UB.

No, the language doesn't work that way.  The compiler must honor the guard (if-statement) around that dereference.

The compiler must honor the C++ language, full stop!  If the compiler generates a speculative load of the null pointer (possible on some ISAs like Itanium), that must be conditional and ignorable, because the program explicitly said not to.

Meanwhile, the hardware must honor the ISA, period!  If the hardware generates a speculative load of the null pointer, that also must be conditional and ignorable, because the machine code program explicitly said not to.

> via [[likely]] and [[unlikely]] … this is seperate to the branch prediction the CPU performs

Code path hints in the C++ language do not necessarily translate into branch prediction hints in machine code.

Many ISAs do not have (or their implementations do not use) machine code branch direction hints.  This is because hardware branch prediction has gotten so good that it is done very early and doesn't need the hint.  In order to use the hint, the instruction has to decoded, which  happens later than we'd like in processor stages for prediction.

What the C++ compiler can do with those hints though is rearrange the machine code so that the likely path is straight and contiguous and the unlikely paths are relocated elsewhere, out of the way of the straight path.

Answer (score 6):

Branch prediction does not have anything to do with **UB**.

**UB** is C or C++ **language** concept abstracted from the actual implementation. It can be only analyzed on the **source code** level. If there is a UB in your code then the compiler is basically free to do what it wants as the **standard** does not specify what should happen in this case

If your source code does not invoke UB, then the compiler **has to** emit the code which (when executed) will have the same **observable behaviour** on all platforms.

> in C++20 via [[likely]] and [[unlikely]] (see preference) this is
> seperate to the branch prediction the CPU performs

It existed long before  C++20 as compiler extensions (for example GCC `__builtin_expect`) and is only a *hint* to the compiler to help it better understand your program flow. In "normal" programming it is a very rarely used feature and you should use it only in very specific cases when it can significantly improve the performance (for example writing the low-level parts of OS kernel or fast device drivers)

I would rather suggest focusing on the language itself (understanding the concepts) rather than esoteric implementation details.

Comment: I would not say that UB is at "source code" level but rather at level of code execution on the "abstract machine" defined by C standard.

Comment: @MarekR: [“mandating feedback for \[downvotes\] would *massively* impede the way Stack Exchange currently works”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325417). [Asking for reasons for downvotes as a comment is discouraged.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment) (I have not yet voted on this answer.)

Comment: @tstanisl when it is compiled end executed it is usually quite well defined. It is not defined on the abstract machine level

Comment: *If your source code does not invoke UB* - More precisely, the compiler has to make asm that works correctly *for all **inputs** that don't cause the abstract machine to encounter UB*, like @tstanisl said. For example, `++x;` can have signed overflow UB, but only for one value of `x`; the behaviour is well-defined for all others.  So the compiler has to make asm that works for at least those values, but is allowed to do something weird if `x` was `INT_MIN`.  That's why `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` can make that case crash but other cases run normally, and still be a compliant C++ implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes It was far too detailed to include in this answer and it would not change the logic of it.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of speculative execution is that it is hidden from you as a programmer. If you want to get insipration to possible ways this might be implemented you could for example look at how they do speculative execution in [BOOM](https://docs.boom-core.org/en/latest/sections/execution-stages.html#branch-unit-branch-speculation).

The C++ action of accessing a nullpointer will probably map to something like trying to access memory at an invalid address in the machine code. If this were to happen a TRAP would occur, but if it happens speculatively I suspect speculative execution would wait for the branch to be confirmed before issuing the trap.

The Boom docs say the following about misspeculation:

> If a branch (or jump) is misspeculated, the Branch Unit must redirect the PC to the correct target, kill the Front-end and Fetch Buffer, and broadcast the misspeculated branch tag so that all dependent, inflight UOPs<Micro-Op (UOP) may be killed. The PC redirect signal goes out immediately, to decrease the misprediction penalty. However, the kill signal is delayed a cycle for critical path reasons.

Comment: it is how RISC-V works.

Comment: That's correct, the CPU doesn't actually raise an exception from a div by 0 or page-fault load/store until that instruction becomes non-speculative, at retirement.  On Intel CPUs, some page-fault loads did speculatively produce a value (on TLB hit on a kernel page, even in user-space) which later speculative instructions could use; combined with a side-channel to read microarchitectural state (cache contents) into architectural state (register values), this is the Meltdown vulnerability.

Comment: [Out-of-order execution vs. speculative execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661172) - Instead of actually triggering faults but suppressing them later if mis-speculation is detected, the CPU waits until the faulting operation reaches retirement.

Comment: Also related: [Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64141366) for how the store buffer allows rollback of mis-speculated stores (that wouldn't have faulted), without polluting cache with mis-speculated state.  Because we must avoid letting other cores see the results of mis-speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior is a concept of programming language only. The CPU needs to execute the program as written in assembly code (e.g. generated by a compiler). However, the full definition of the expected behavior is not clear at all. For instance, due to speculative execution and branch misprediction, the CPU may do things that are not expressed by the assembly code, which are not visible in the results, but whose effects are observable via timings. This is what led to vulnerabilities such as [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)).